# Create a image every XX seconds of the video [FFMPEG]

Tags: html5, video, youtube, ffmpeg

Screenshot: [FilmStrip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knFFt.jpg)

I tried `ffmpeg -i video.mkv -vf fps=1 out%d.png`

But It is generating one by one images. I need all thumbnails into one image. as in screenshot above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex \
"select='not(mod(n,30))',scale=120:-1,tile=layout=3x2" \
-vframes 1 -q:v 2 output.jpg
```

- [select](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect) one frame every 30 seconds
- [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) each frame to a smaller size (alternatively you can scale after tile)
- [tile](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tile) each frame into one image. Default grid size is 6x5, so you may have to adjust that with `layout` depending on how many images you want to display.

The process may take some time depending on your input duration and format.

Comment: Would `fps=1` work the same as `select='not(mod(n,30))'`?

Comment: @DamianYerrick You can do that instead of you want each tile to be chosen from one frame per second, but it won't work exactly the same.

Comment: how can i generate one sprite every 5 minutes, within each sprite, one thumbnail per 10 seconds ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -filter:v "select=not(mod(n\,10)),setpts=N/((25)*TB)" -qscale:v 2 frame%03d.jpg
```

- the `select` controls which frames you are grabbing (in this case one out of every 10)
- the `setps` controls the framerate and depends on your source - `25` for PAL or `30000/1001` for NTSC video
- `qscale` controls quality (quantizing scale) of the output frames from 2 (best) to 31 (worst)

***just noticed your edit above, if that gives you the frames you want to use should be fine as a starting point***

you will then need to stitch the images together into the single asset using a tool like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)

```
montage -background "transparent" -depth 8 -type TrueColorMatte frame??.jpg \
    -geometry 50x50 -tile 10x10 -matte -transparent "transparent" \
    -type TrueColorMatte -depth 8 allframes.jpg
```